# Django gives AttributeError - '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'state'

Tags: python-3.x, django, sympy, attributeerror, thread-local

I am creating a django application which requires mathematical computation using the sympy python package.

To give you an example of the kind of computation that is involved lets consider we have three equations-

1. x+y=100
2. y=200
3. z+x=300

I calculate all possible values for x,y and z using the solve() method of sympy package. However, this gives an AttributeError - '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'state'

Below is the complete traceback -

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/results/24/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.10
Installed Applications:
['hlasoftware.apps.HlasoftwareConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\HLA\hlasoftware\views.py", line 163, in results
    reactive_eplets=predict.mfi_predictions(data,cutoff2) #Predict MFI of eplets
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\HLA\hlasoftware\Predict_mfi.py", line 282, in mfi_predictions
    sol=solve_eq(list_of_eq,ep)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\HLA\hlasoftware\Predict_mfi.py", line 133, in solve_eq
    sol=solve((list_of_eq),(list_of_var))
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1096, in solve
    solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1763, in _solve_system
    result = solve_linear_system(matrix, *symbols, **flags)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2237, in solve_linear_system
    inv = inv_quick(system[:, :-1])
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2568, in inv_quick
    return M.inv()
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py", line 2252, in inv
    try_block_diag=try_block_diag)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\inverse.py", line 459, in _inv
    rv = M.inverse_GE(iszerofunc=iszerofunc)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py", line 2236, in inverse_GE
    return _inv_GE(self, iszerofunc=iszerofunc)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\inverse.py", line 242, in _inv_GE
    red = big.rref(iszerofunc=iszerofunc, simplify=True)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py", line 164, in rref
    pivots=pivots, normalize_last=normalize_last)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\reductions.py", line 306, in _rref
    normalize_last, normalize=True, zero_above=True)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\reductions.py", line 129, in _row_reduce
    normalize=normalize, zero_above=zero_above)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\reductions.py", line 60, in _row_reduce_list
    isimp = _get_intermediate_simp(_dotprodsimp)
  File "C:\Users\Anjali Jain\anaconda3\envs\hlaenv\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\utilities.py", line 34, in _get_intermediate_simp
    if dotprodsimp is False or _dotprodsimp_state.state is False:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /results/24/
Exception Value: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'state'
```

I have tried the following hacks but all give the same error-

1. Reinstalling sympy package
2. Using python manage.py --runserver --nothreading
3. Using python manage.py --runserver --nothreading --noreload

Any suggestion/feedback on how to resolve this error will be much appreciated. Please help me out here!

Comment: Can you also post your code? This would include views.py and Predict_mfi.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in sympy 1.6.1 that has been fixed although the fix is not yet released:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19809

You can use sympy 1.6.0 or the latest sympy master from git or otherwise apply the fix manually.

Comment: Thank you so much! Downgrading to version 1.6.0 solved the problem.